# Manually requesting the HAML file

Tags: sinatra, haml

If I want to manually request a particular HAML file in Sinatra, it looks like this works:

```
get '/' do
  haml_file = File.open('views/index.haml').read
  haml haml_file
end
```

My question is, do you have any reasons to believe that this is more inefficient than using the conventional method?

```
get '/' do
  haml :index
end
```

Maybe Sinatra does a more "efficient" reading a file than what I did manually?

If my manual method is no good, please suggest an alternative way to manually get at the HAML file, located in a particular path. (reason being that the paths are not always that simple).

Comment: Is your problem just trying to specify view files that aren’t just simple words (e.g. if they are in subdirectories)? If so you can create complex symbols using quotes, e.g. `haml :"subdir/view_file.haml"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying you don't keep all your views in the same directory? That's a pain, but up to you. You could use [Sinatra-Partial](https://github.com/yb66/Sinatra-Partial) (I'm the maintainer) if it's getting at sub-directories of the `view` directory you need. Otherwise, what you've done is fine, it's difficult to see how it could improved the efficiency for such a small text file. The only thing you might want to add is headers for caching.

---

Additional:

This is pretty standard nowadays, right?

```
config.ru
app/
  main.rb
  public/
  helpers/
  models/
  views/
    mobile/
    stylesheets/
    whatever/
    _partial1.haml
    _partial2.haml
    layout.haml
specs/
```

Comment: I can't imagine why people would want ALL their views in the same dir. How is that even maintainable for larger websites? Websites have different sections in them, and it's natural to want to separate them somehow in the filesystem? Say apple.com, apple.com/imac, apple.com/imac/specs, whatever. Maybe nice to separate the root site from the imac site? Let me know your thought process here. I'm a bit confused..

Comment: @user2015453 How many views do you need? The size of the website doesn't matter, the whole point of views is to reuse them. I think sub-dirs off of the main `views` dir, and (if you wish) adding an underscore to partials is enough. I've added a faily standard layout to my answer, most people do something similar to Rails, as most of that was a good idea (if a little bit _too_ Java like for my taste).